# Is there a way to execute appium testcase on AWS linux instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, appium, android-virtual-device

I want to execute my set of Test suite on AWS Linux instance using appium .
Things needed are a AVD , appium server .
I am unable to do so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [docker container](https://github.com/appium/appium-docker-android) with openJDK, Android SDK, Appium and emulator on Linux AWS instance. The thing is, to run your tests smoothly linux machine should support [KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) - in this case you able to create x86 emulator. Without it you are limited to use super slow ARM emulators - bad idea.

As an option, you may look into [genymotion-on-demand](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MREUQPU/) in AWS. Should suit you need.